# TImage width with double value instead integer

Tags: delphi, vcl

How can I set TImage size as double value? Example Image1.width := 50.1; or what component accept it, because TImage only accept integer values.

I'm working with download files, and one image should be the number of elements to download, so Image1.width max value is 340, i need to divide this value by the amount of files who will be downloaded, and increase this value on image1.width when every download be finished, but TImage only accept Integer value.

I already did it using "Round" but it is not what I need.

Comment: If you are using fireMonkey then the size is in Single else if you are using VCL then forget It

Comment: Maybe if we understood what you were trying to accomplish we could point you to a more viable solution. For example, maybe instead of a `TImage`, perhaps a `TPaintBox` using GDI+ for drawing, which does support drawing on a decimal scale.

Comment: This question looks like a kind of "XY problem". Perhaps you don't need float control width, instead your real problem might be solved by other means. Progress indicator?

Comment: If all integers need to be the same same size then use spacer bars to pad unused space, with any unevenness taken up by the two end bars. You would also need to round down, not round, otherwise the images will overlap, so use the div operator..

Comment: It is unclear what problem you try to solve, please improve your problem description and provide a [mcve] showing what you have tried sofar.

Answer (score 2):

As [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55480275/243614), you cannot set the image's size to any floating point value.

However, using [coordinate spaces and transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/coordinate-spaces-and-transformations) functions, you can set an arbitrary transformation between a logical coordinate system and the viewing device. This can be used to increase the logical extent of the image's canvas size with each download and yet keep the image on the screen with an entirely different size.

The below example demonstrates the concept by drawing 4 rows and 4 columns of a 256x256 image on a 105x105 bitmap canvas of a TPicture of a TImage. Basically it achieves to draw a single 256x256 image on a 26.25x26.25 px. surface.

```
uses
  pngimage;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  Col = 4;
  Row = 4;
var
  Png: TPngImage;
  ImgCanvas: TCanvas;
  ExtX, ExtY: Integer;
  MapMode: Integer;
  Size: TSize;
  i, j: Integer;
begin
  Png := TPngImage.Create;
  try
    Png.LoadFromFile('...\Attention.png');
    Png.Draw(Canvas, Rect(0, 0, Png.Width, Png.Height)); // original picture

    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := Color;
    Image1.Picture.Bitmap.SetSize(Image1.Width, Image1.Height);
    ImgCanvas := Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Canvas;

    SetStretchBltMode(ImgCanvas.Handle, HALFTONE);

    MapMode := SetMapMode(ImgCanvas.Handle, MM_ISOTROPIC);
    if MapMode <> 0 then
      try
        ExtX := Png.Width * Col;
        ExtY := Png.Height * Row;

        if not GetWindowExtEx(ImgCanvas.Handle, Size) then
          RaiseLastOSError;
        if not SetWindowExtEx(ImgCanvas.Handle, Size.cx * ExtX div Image1.Width,
            Size.cy * ExtY div Image1.Height, nil) then
          RaiseLastOSError;
        if not SetViewportExtEx(ImgCanvas.Handle, Size.cx, Size.cy, nil) then
          RaiseLastOSError;

        i := 0;
        j := 0;
        while j < ExtY do begin
          while i < ExtX do begin
            Png.Draw(ImgCanvas, Rect(i, j, i + Png.Width, j + Png.Height));
            Inc(i, Png.Width);
          end;
          i := 0;
          Inc(j, Png.Height);
        end;
      finally
        SetMapMode(ImgCanvas.Handle, MapMode);
      end
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  finally
    Png.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Probably worth noting that GDI may not be the best graphics system when scaling is involved. For quick reference, here's what the above yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the VCL framework, all controls across Delphi are `Integer` based. You simply cannot assign a float value, not without first converting it to an integer.

The Firemonkey framework on the other hand is widely based on float values.

Comment: Yes, i'm working with VCL. Desktop application. Any solution for that?

Comment: @PâmellaDouglas I already explained your options in my answer.

Comment: There is no solution because there is no problem. TImage is based on raster images.